# java, c#, javascript correct way to send post and get according to api cignal

Tags: javascript, java, c#, video-streaming, streaming

I cannot understand the instruction of the cignal api. I just copy all the instruction and paste it here.

```
//API instruction start here

API Base URI: https://cplayapi.cignal.tv

Authorization

POST /Token

Parameter   :    Value
grant_type  :    password
username    :    {yourusername}
password    :    {yourpassword}

API 

Playback

GET api/channels/playback/{assetid}/{userid}/{protocol}

Header      : Value
Authorization : Bearer [token]

Parameter   : Value
assetid     : 6005
userid      : appdevtest001@cignalt.com.ph
protocol    : ISM, DASH or HLS

//API instruction End here
```

My question is how to put header value and parameter value if it is get request?

What i tried is java code.

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://cplayapi.cignal.tv/";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "TextBox1="+MYUSERNAME+"&TextBox2="+MYPASS+"&submit=\'Get Token\'";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

    // HTTP GET request
private void sendGet() throws Exception {   
    //String url = "api/channels/playback{assetid}/{userid}/{protocol}";
            String url = "api/channels/playback/6005/appdevtest001@cignalt.com.ph/HLS";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

Any correction to my code or any sample code for `java`, `javascript` or `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your parameter names.

```
   String urlParameters = "TextBox1="+MYUSERNAME+"&TextBox2="+MYPASS+"&submit=\'Get Token\'";
```

here the parameters must be:

```
   grant_type=password
   username={yourusername}
   password{yourpassword}
```

In order to test the API before actually implementing in your code you can use Postman https://www.getpostman.com/